# Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality Variations

Tags: real-analysis

We have
[image]

When is this a strict inequality? Do we have any good ways of estimating their difference? We have equality for n = 1 and it is strict for n = 2. I would like to figure the rest out by induction perhaps? But I can't seem to find a way to relate the expressions for the n case and the n+1 case (not immediately anyway) I saw a proof of AG-GM using convexity of -log but I am not sure that would be much help for my question.

Comment: The proof can be found in a very old math book titled: Inequalities by Edwin Beckenbach by MAA. I saw one a very long time ago that they used $n = 2^k$ in the inductive step...

Comment: We always have equality for $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$. And always inequality otherwise.

Comment: I recommend looking at Hardy, Littlewood and Polya's book titled "Inequalities".